# "Чья возьмёт" - значение

Tags: значения

> А наверху ещё посмотрим, чья возьмёт.

(В. Березин, *Путевые знаки*)

Значит ли это предложение то же, что

> А наверху ещё посмотрим, кто победит.

?

Comment: Да, именно так. За исключением того, что "кто победит" звучит формально и скучно. Неудивительно, что автор выбрал другое выражение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чья возьмёт
(разгоговорное, экспрессивное) - кто выиграет в каком-либо деле; кто победит, одолеет.

> Мне казалось, что России нет и уже никогда не будет, что всё потеряно и жить дальше не к чему. «Посмотрим, чья возьмёт, — подумал я. — Посмотрим»        (Паустовский. Повесть о жизни).

Answer (score 5):

This also means `let's see which side will win` where `чья` - means `чья сторона`.
There is also a phrase `наша (сторона) взяла` that we use

Answer (score -4):

И в то же время речевой оборот лукавый, с подтекстом на случай конфуза:

> А всё равно моя жена взяла меня, а не противника по спору, моего
> соседа.

Это манера демагогов, софистов строить речь, чтобы потом можно было "передёрнуть" понятия.